# Spring controller to invoke other contorllers

Tags: spring

I am trying come up with one master controller that will take care of invoking multiple controllers (one or more ) as required , merge the data , filter the data and return it back.
Consumers don't need to worry abt these multiple endpoints in system. they just talk to this master endpoint.

Is this right approach ? Please suggest

```
ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception {

    final HandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerMapping.class);
    final HandlerExecutionChain handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
    assertNotNull("No handler found for request, check you request mapping", handler);

    final Object controller = handler.getHandler();
    // if you want to override any injected attributes do it here

    final HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors =
        handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getInterceptors();
    for (HandlerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
        final boolean carryOn = interceptor.preHandle(request, response, controller);
        if (!carryOn) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/query", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView execute() throws Exception {
    request.setRequestURI("/test.html");
    request.setMethod("GET");
    return handle(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spring MVC framework is already this master controller.

The sub controller are the classes annotated with `@Controller` and the filters are called [Handler Interceptor](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/) and must implement the `HandlerInterceptor` Interface (or extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`)

So in order to come back to your question: "Is this right approach?" -- No it is not, because it exists already.

Comment: But i need a controller that can work with multiple controllers .

Comment: Suppose If UI needs data from 3 rest-endpoints. instead of UI making all these calls , i got this Contoller that can work with other controllers ( 3 end points) , filter the data and return it.  instead of 3 http requests , i do this with 1 http request. UI talks to this one master endpoint. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: So you have one controller and different services?

Comment: i m doing some thing similar to this chaining the controllers. http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/02/spring-in-chains.html .

Comment: I have 3 contorller that's dedicated to do their job and additional one controller that does chaining , if the UI needs data from 3 controllers ( end points ). so here instead of making 3 http requests to get the required to render on page , they will make 1 http request.

Comment: @Srini you have Front Controller - it is the Dispatcher Servlet in Spring, as for the chaining controllers there were many attempts to do this, but no solutions exist because there are many mapping types and controller methods may diverse in arguments / return types. It took several years before SpringSource could roll out Spring MVC Testing framework for example. So it's bad idea to fight the framework. And I how can the internal configuration of the controllers affect the number of http requests(why not add additional coarse grained controller method & encapsulate the logic in services) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create 1 controller (master controller) then autowire the controllers you need and invoke the methods of those controller.

Eg.

```
@Controller
public class MasterController {
   @Autowired
   private Controller1 controller1;
   @Autowired
   private Controller1 controller2;

   @RequestMapping("/master/sample")
   public Sample getSample() {
        Sample sample1 = controller1.getSample():
        Sample sample2 = controller2.getSample():
        // additional processing
   }
}

@Controller
public class Controller1 {
   @RequestMapping("/controller1/sample")
   public Sample getSample() {
        return something;
   }
}
```